# How to make Stripe Setup Intent with Stripe Elements

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Is it possible to make [Setup Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/setup-intents) (and generated client secret) work with [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/elements) and how?

Asking as currently only [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) allows users to use wallets (e.g. Google Pay, Apple Pay) on web for setup intents.

Another option for using setup intent is [Stripe Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element) that currently only support cards as well.

Looking for Stripe solution to use mobile wallets for setup intent.

Answer (score 1):

The joys of Stripe!

Yes, you can use Stripe Elements to create a SetupIntent.

Their online docs have gotten a lot better, but it's still a pile of tangled spaghetti...

In your client js code:

```
            const stripe = Stripe('{{$pk_PublishableKey}}');
            const clientSecret = '{{$clientSecret}}';

            const appearance = {
                /* appearance */
            };
            const options = {
                layout: {
                    type: 'tabs',
                    defaultCollapsed: true,
                },
                captureMethod: 'manual',   // This line is important.
            };
            const elements = stripe.elements({
```

... (a bit more code from Stripe's js example here...)

```
                // Confirm the setupIntent that was created server side:
                const {
                    error
                } = await stripe.confirmSetup({   // This is important
                    elements,
                    confirmParams: {
                        return_url: `${window.location.origin}/return.php`
                    }
                });
```

Hope this helps someone miss the hours of digging in Stripe's docs.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe's [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements) product is a UI library that lets you collect payment method details client-side. It still has to be paired with a component on your server though.

Client-side, you use your Publishable API key `pk_live_123` to confirm a PaymentIntent or SetupIntent that you first created server-side using your Secret API key `sk_live_123`.

It is not possible to create a SetupIntent client-side for that reason. You confirm an existing SetupIntent client-side, usually using [PaymentElement](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element), but you first create it on your server.

Comment: When you create setup intent on your server you can use the generated client secret and then pass it to Stipe Checkout UI library. The question is whether this can be done with Stripe Elements.

Comment: I think you're mixing things up here. You do not create a SetupIntent with Checkout at all. Checkout is a hosted payment page documented here https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout and you would just redirect your customer to Checkout's url. Elements lets you collect payment method details client-side and takes that client-secret. It's covered in Stripe docs in details https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Elements (Stripe Payment Element) let you use client secret - https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create not Checkout as I've previously falsely claimed. 

However the question whether you can use setup intent with Stripe Elements still remains the same. Asking as Stripe Payment Element do not support wallets on web as I'm aware.

Comment: I think you're still mixing things up. PaymentElement does work with both PaymentIntent and SetupIntent, and it also supports wallets like Apple Pay and Google Pay out of the box in both cases.

Comment: "PaymentElement does work with both PaymentIntent and SetupIntent" if that is the case would be great if you provide sample code for web - speaking strictly for SETUPINTENT.

Comment: That's exactly what I linked you to on Oct 23: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse it has a clear `Custom payment flow` tab that is literally using PaymentElement + SetupIntent